# Pickling of files result in file type as Binary (application/octet-stream)

Tags: python, python-3.x, pickle

I am doing some experiments in tensor flow and I collect some of the internediate measurements in numpy arrays and python dicts which are pickled at the end. However, when I try to load them, it takes a very long amount of time even when the pickled file is only about 20 MB. When i click on the Properties and see its type, it shows as `Binary (application/octet-stream)`.

Even a simple command like `type(filename)` takes a very long time, and running the command shows the correct file type as `dict`. But checking the file properties, it still shows up as Binary (application/octet-stream).

How do I make them get saved as original numpy arrays instead of getting converted to this format, or how do I get back the original numpy arrays from this format?

Edit 1: all data is numeric, i.e int or float.

Comment: you're using `pickle.dump(..., file_handle)`? so you can use `pickle.load(file_handle)` to get it back into its original format. If you want to save your results to disk they have to be "serialized" and `pickle` is once such tool for doing that. Serializing is converting objects in memory into a stream of bytes (binary) and deserializing is converting that stream back in to something useful in memory.

Comment: @Macattack I am using `pickle.load()`. I checked some more files and it could be the data is gets stored in its tensor format, as I wrap my python environment in a tf environment. I will add more details if I can resolve this issue.

Comment: silly question but did you assign the pickle.load() to a variable so that you can use it afterwards without unpicking again? Keep in mind that 20 mb dictionary or array is a pretty big object.

Comment: @Charalamm yes I did, and both the process of assigning the data from the pickle object to the variable, and doing some operation on the variable take a lot of time. I was thinking 20 MB is not a big deal.

Comment: cpu cach has 254 kb to 8 mb so with 20 mb you are constantly transfering data to and from the disc. I am not good with these concepts but that might be the problem, the 20mb